# How to determine the active network interface media type?

Tags: windows, go

I'm trying to determine if the current active/default network is wifi or ethernet in a reasonable reliable way. Windows offers a command `netsh.exe interface ipv4 show interfaces` This seems to be reliable except I don't really like shelling out to the CLI for this sort of thing. At least things are reasonable in Windows. The OSX analog is far less reliable or accurate. Using the `net.Interface` is not reliable as `FlagUp` is also ambiguous. My next test might be to check for `FlagBooadcast` per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/124453/how-can-i-scan-the-local-network-for-connected-devices-mac-os)

Comment: If you don't want to shell out, you'll have to find the appropriate system call for each supported OS and call it with cgo. This is going to require a different implementation for each supported OS either way.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the answer varies based on the OS.  This question was specific to OSX. The biggest challenge is that it is possible, but unusual, to have two active and route-able devices on a personal computer that is not bridging networks. That's more of a server function... In my case I'm interested in the ONE network media device. And that can be complicated...

On OSX there is an OS tool that dumps the device types in priority order with their accompanying device name.

```
networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder
```

I had to capture the output then parse it in order to call the following `isactive` function.

```
func isactive(name string) bool {
    if iface, err := net.InterfaceByName(name); err!=nil {
        log.Printf("could not locate %s interface - %v", name, err)
    } else {
        if addrs, err := iface.Addrs(); err!=nil || len(addrs)==0 {
            log.Printf("could not locate %s addr - %v", name, err)
            return false
        }
        if iface.Flags & net.FlagBroadcast == net.FlagBroadcast && iface.Flags & net.FlagUp == net.FlagUp {
            //log.Printf("%s is active", name)
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

In retrospect there is one other thing to note... `iface.Addrs()` could return more than one IP address. But again unlikely in the normal use-case.